# How to wipe out all forms/grid data in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I have a Silverlight 3 business app set up with RIA Services. I use a domain datasource to connect to the backend and fetch the data and populate a series of dataforms and grids bound to this datasource.

The issue is that we require tight security and currently when a user logs out and another logs back in on the same machine the forms/grids briefly display information from the last login before the DDS gets the new set.

What's the best approach to wiping out all the data when the user logs out in Silverlight?  For legal reasons we can't chance any data hanging around, so is there a way to tell Silverlight to go back to its initial state?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution: turns out that by simply removing the NavigationCacheMode="Enabled" from each of the pages, logging out now correctly clears out all the form/grid data cleanly and simply.

Before finding this solution though I did run across [this method to clear all the form/grid data on a page](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/73069/174515.aspx) but for my case, the solution above works much better.